# How to take and use an instance variable in a class?

Tags: python, class, methods

```
 class human:
    def speech(self,x):
        print(x, (THE NAME OF THE JACK) )

 jack = human()
 jack.speech("hi")
```

how i can take the "jack" as string and print in "def speech"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take it as an argument in `__init__`, and set that attribute for the instance:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def speech(self, x):
        print(x, self.name)

jack = Human(name="Jack")
jack.speech("Hi")
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Hi Jack
> ```